# Python ConfigParser interpolation from foreign section

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, configparser, python-2.4

With Python ConfigParser, is it possible to use interpolation across foreign sections?  My mind seems to tell me I've seen that it's possible somewhere, but I can't find it when searching.

This example doesn't work, but it's to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
[section1]
root = /usr

[section2]
root = /usr/local

[section3]
dir1 = $(section1:root)/bin
dir2 = $(section2:root)/bin
```

Note that I'm using Python 2.4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In python 3.2 and up this is perfectly valid:

```
[Common]
home_dir: /Users
library_dir: /Library
system_dir: /System
macports_dir: /opt/local

[Frameworks]
Python: 3.2
path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/

[Arthur]
nickname: Two Sheds
last_name: Jackson
my_dir: ${Common:home_dir}/twosheds
my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
python_dir: ${Frameworks:path}/Python/Versions/${Frameworks:Python}
```

---

## Edit:

I just saw that you are using *python 2.4*, so ***no***, section interpolation cannot be done in *python 2.4*.  It was introduced in *python 3.2* - [See section 13.2.5 - ConfigParser Interpolation of values](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/configparser.html#module-configparser).

> **class `configparser.ExtendedInterpolation`**
>
> An alternative handler
>   for interpolation which implements a more advanced syntax, used for
>   instance in zc.buildout. Extended interpolation is using
>   ${section:option} to denote a value from a foreign section.
>   Interpolation can span multiple levels. For convenience, if the
>   section: part is omitted, interpolation defaults to the current
>   section (and possibly the default values from the special section).
>   For example, the configuration specified above with basic
>   interpolation, would look like this with extended interpolation:
>
> ```
>    [Paths]
>    home_dir: /Users
>    my_dir: ${home_dir}/lumberjack
>    my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
> ```
>
> Values from other sections can be fetched as well:
>
> ```
>    [Common]
>    home_dir: /Users
>    library_dir: /Library
>    system_dir: /System
>    macports_dir: /opt/local
>
>    [Frameworks]
>    Python: 3.2
>    path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/
>
>    [Arthur]
>    nickname: Two Sheds
>    last_name: Jackson
>    my_dir: ${Common:home_dir}/twosheds
>    my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
>    python_dir: ${Frameworks:path}/Python/Versions/${Frameworks:Python}
> ```

Comment: Looks like your syntax is a bit different than mind.  You're using ${section:name} instead of what I was using, %(section:name)s.  I tried this and didn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didnt realize you were referring to string interpolation across sections.  I believe that came with 3.2 as well, let me double check.

Comment: I just found what you have here in the Python 3.2 docs (configparser.ExtendedInterpolation), but it doesn't list when this was added.  When I look at the Python 2.4 docs (what I'm using), this isn't shown.  I'm guessing it was added somewhere in between 2.4 and 3.2.

Comment: Yea, I checked each versions docs from 2.4 to 3.2 for ConfigParser and the first one to have the ExtendedInterpolation class was 3.2.

Comment: They should probably add "New in Python 3.2" to the docs.  It comes in handy.

Comment: Agreed!  And usually they do; seems this one got skipped :/

Answer (score 2):

You do have access to the special-case [DEFAULT] section.  Values defined here can be accessed via interpolation from other sections even for older versions of Python.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? and possibly an example please. Or even the source reference.

Comment: Hamed, take a look here.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html.  Basically (and you can download and read the code) if you try to read the 'value' for a 'name' from a specific [section], but there is no 'name=value' in that [section], then the config parser looks in the [DEFAULT] section for a 'name=value' and returns that if present.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with python 2.7 and you need to do cross-section interpolation it is easy enough to do this by hand using regexps.

Here is the code:

```
INTERPOLATION_RE = re.compile(r"\$\{(?:(?P<section>[^:]+):)?(?P<key>[^}]+)\}")

def load_something_from_cp(cp, section="section"):
    result = []
    def interpolate_func(match):
        d = match.groupdict()
        section = d.get('section', section)
        key = d.get('key')
        return cp.get(section, key)
    for k, v in cp.items(section):
        v = re.sub(INTERPOLATION_RE, interpolate_func, v)
        result.append(
            (v, k)
        )
    return result
```

Caveeats:

- There is no recursion in interpolation
- When parsing many sections, youll need to somehow guess current section.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this in the project I'm working on right now, and I implemented a quick extension to the `ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser` class in which I have overwritten the `get()` function. I thought some may find it useful.

```
import re
import ConfigParser

class ExtParser(ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser):
     #implementing extended interpolation
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.cur_depth = 0 
         ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


     def get(self, section, option, raw=False, vars=None):
         r_opt = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser.get(self, section, option, raw=True, vars=vars)
         if raw:
             return r_opt

         ret = r_opt
         re_oldintp = r'%\((\w*)\)s'
         re_newintp = r'\$\{(\w*):(\w*)\}'

         m_new = re.findall(re_newintp, r_opt)
         if m_new:
             for f_section, f_option in m_new:
                 self.cur_depth = self.cur_depth + 1 
                 if self.cur_depth < ConfigParser.MAX_INTERPOLATION_DEPTH:
                     sub = self.get(f_section, f_option, vars=vars)
                     ret = ret.replace('${{{0}:{1}}}'.format(f_section, f_option), sub)
                 else:
                     raise ConfigParser.InterpolationDepthError, (option, section, r_opt)



         m_old = re.findall(re_oldintp, r_opt)
         if m_old:
             for l_option in m_old:
                 self.cur_depth = self.cur_depth + 1 
                 if self.cur_depth < ConfigParser.MAX_INTERPOLATION_DEPTH:
                     sub = self.get(section, l_option, vars=vars)
                     ret = ret.replace('%({0})s'.format(l_option), sub)
                 else:
                     raise ConfigParser.InterpolationDepthError, (option, section, r_opt)

         self.cur_depth = self.cur_depth - 1 
         return ret
```