# ExtendedInterpolation() in the Python 2.7 ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, refactoring, interpolation

I have Python script written in 3.x version which I need to transform in 2.7 due to environment limitations.

I managed to refactor most of the syntax difs and module imports but I came across one line which I do not know how to handle:

```
def readConfigFile(self, file):
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(interpolation = ConfigParser.ExtendedInterpolation())
        config.optionxform = str
        config.read(file)

**config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(interpolation = ConfigParser.ExtendedInterpolation())**
```

I found some reference here (
[Python ConfigParser interpolation from foreign section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605124/python-configparser-interpolation-from-foreign-section)) , but I do not know exactly how this can be replaced(refactored).

The **ConfigParser :**

- in the 2.7 version : https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html, but the ExtendedInterpolation() is not present
- in the 3.x version : https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/configparser.html ,

So my question , is there any way to refactor the code above to work in python 2.7 and retain functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in another question ([Python ConfigParser interpolation from foreign section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605124/python-configparser-interpolation-from-foreign-section)) no, unfortunately there is not an easy way to do this.  You would need to create your own parser for the returned values and iterate over them.  This seems a bit kludgy though.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in ArcPy 2.7 by using

```
from backports import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
config.read('path/to/the/config_file.cfg')
```

I then used the following code in my config file:

```
[Section 1]
foo: bar
```

...

```
[Section 5]
foo:  ${Section1:foo}
```

Trying the call in the interpreter produces the predicted results:

```
config['Section 5']['foo']
>>> bar
```